# How to use other modules like Tailwindcss in our Nuxt module?

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxt-module

I am trying to build a nuxt module that uses tailwindcss. I don't know how to import it so that the component in runtime dir can use tailwindcss classes.

Comment: Follow their documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs)

Comment: I already use tailwind in nuxt projects but nuxt modules are something different. We build nuxt modules to be used in nuxt modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot in the Nuxt documentation, I noticed that there was no guide for this. After I found out how to do it, I created a [PR](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/22081) on the Nuxt repository and contributed to their documentation. So, the answer is that you can use Nuxt Kit's `installModule` utility to import other modules in your module. You can view the documentation [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/modules#using-other-modules-in-your-module)